# remove \pagebreak after \part

Tags: formatting, titlesec, parts

I am use the `book` documentclass with various parts.  For a part, I'd like the Part number and title followed by a paragraph on the same page.  Currently, I'm getting the Part number and title on a page, with the rest of the page blank, the following page blank and then a page with the paragraph.

Also, I'm using the `titlesec` package to reformat them and realize there is spacing in the `\titleformat` command, but it appears that no control over the spacing will remove the page break.

I also tried refining `\@endpart`, however that didn't work.  I wonder if this conflicts with the `titlesec` package.

**Edited Below**

With the answer below, here's a twist on the code with `\titleformat` defined which shows that redefining `\@endpart` doesn't seem to work:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\part}
  {\huge\sffamily\slshape}
  {Part~\thepart:}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@endpart}{}
\makeatother

\part{A part}
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `titlesec` package hardwires the new page after the title without using the `\@endpart` mechanism.

Here's a patch:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttl@page@ii}{\newpage\if@twoside}{\iffalse}{}{}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\part}
  {\huge\sffamily\slshape}
  {Part~\thepart:}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\part{A part}
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
% partpageprob.tex  SE 553544
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@endpart}{}
\makeatother

\part{A part}
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

If you are using twocolumns, and possibly some pagestyles, the definition of `\@endpart` may need modifying instead of just cancelling its effect.

I would have found it useful if you had provided an MWE; I had to make one up but it does not necessarily have much to do with your actual code.

Comment: It seems like it is an interaction with the `titlesec` package.  If use the `explicit` option on the `titlesec` package and add the following command:
`\titleformat{\part}{\huge\sffamily\slshape}{Part \thepart:}{1em}{#1}`

The page break comes back.