# Remove blank space following a part (\part)

Tags: spacing, parts

I'm having trouble removing the blank space after starting a new part.

What I ideally want is for my text to appear straight after my part heading, i.e.:

> **Introduction**
>
> TextTextText

However Latex is inserting blank space 'til the end of the page after a new section starts, as shown here:

[image: Picture showing two pages. An "introduction" heading is on the first page followed by blank space so that text begins on the following page.]

How can I make it so that the text begins straight after the part's heading?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,parskip=full,BCOR10mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{-48pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-48pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{-48pt}{0pt} 
\AtBeginDocument{
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\LARGE}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\large}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\date{November 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\part*{Introduction}
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Note that `titlesec` is not recommended to be used in combination with KOMA classes such as `scrbook`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73288/47927

Comment: Further, this question might already have an answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553544/47927

Comment: @Jasper Habicht
Yes thank you, that works!